# Set label text using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to set label text using Jquery. Problem is that label contain text box. Whenever i set label text , textbox within the label get removed. The label code is given below-

```
<label> Search:<input id="search" type="text" ></label>
```

and i am trying to set label with JQuery code given below-

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            $("#search").parent().append("some Text");                      
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //get clone copy of input  
            var $input = $("#search").clone();                      
            //replace text in parent  
            var $parent = $("#search").parent();
            $parent.text("some Text");
            //append input again
            $parent.append($input);
        });
</script>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/ez15fuy1/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = $("#search");
$("#search").parent().text("some Text").append(input);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yann86/ez15fuy1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contents()` to get the nodes within the element, and `filter` to specifically retrieve the textNodes. With that in mind, this will work for you:

```
$("#search").closest('label').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).first()[0].nodeValue = 'Some text:';
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/hsud541z/)

Alternatively, if you change your HTML structure to place a `span` around the label text you can simplify the code a lot:

```
<label> 
    <span>Search:</span>
    <input id="search" type="text" />
</label>
```

```js
$("#search").siblings('span').text('Some text:');
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<label id="lab"> Search:<input id="search" type="text"></label>
     <button>change label</button>

 $('button').on('click' ,function(){
   var input = $("#search");
   $("#lab").text("some Text").append(input);
 })
```